# Slowly Changing Dimensions Type 4

Tags: data-warehouse, slowly-changing-dimension

SCD type 4 keeps the foreign keys to the original dimension and the mini-dimension in the fact table.
Why is the foreign key to the mini-dim not stored in the original dim?

Link to an article explaining SCD types: http://www.kimballgroup.com/2013/02/design-tip-152-slowly-changing-dimension-types-0-4-5-6-7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, we use `SCD-type-4` when a dimension(`SCD Type 2`) **grows** rapidly due to the frequently changing of its attributes. These frequently changing attributes will be removed from the main dimension and added in to a new one known as `Mini-Dimension`.

==> *`Mini Dimension do not store the historical attributes, but the fact table preserved the history of dimension attribute assignment`*

A good example is illustrated here : [link-SCD4](http://www.disoln.org/2013/04/SCD-Type-4-a-solution-for-Rapidly-Changing-Dimension.html)